# Problem with permission to run an activity

Tags: android, permissions

I`m trying to understand, how permissions work in android. I made simple project: 1 source file and 1 xml-layout. And:

1) I define permission to activity (activity name is "AndroidTestActivity", permission name is "android.permission.MY_PERMISSION"),

2) I define uses-permission for activity (),
My problem is: when I run AndroidTestActivity, logcat says:

```
08-19 19:39:18.311: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.Android.Test/.AndroidTestActivity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.MY_PERMISSION
```

Why do I get Permission Denial? I made uses-permission, isn`t it enough?

Here is AndroidManifest source:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Android.Test" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MY_PERMISSION" android:protectionLevel="normal"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MY_PERMISSION"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidTestActivity" android:permission="android.permission.MY_PERMISSION"
        android:label="Sample menus application">
             <intent-filter> 
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
             </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is AndroidTestActivity source:

```
  public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Menu myMenu=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedlnstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedlnstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/security/security.html#declaring) it should smth like this:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.Android.Test.permission.MY_PERMISSION"
     android:protectionLevel="normal" 
     android:description="Some description" 
     android:label="Some label" />
<uses-permission 
     android:name="com.example.Android.Test.permission.MY_PERMISSION" />
```